# Android - Failed linking references giving APPT2 Error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm having problem with my android studio. I have try assamble debug, Clean and rebuild the project, invalidate and restart and so on but i am unable to find the actuly problem plz help me and tanx in advance. i m attaching my assemble debug logs

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Asif Raza\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\sdp-android-1.0.6.aar\\04b6da1e83897bce29707a666e8fc5e9\\res\\values\\values.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Asif Raza\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\sdp-android-1.0.6.aar\\04b6da1e83897bce29707a666e8fc5e9\\res\\values\\values.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Comment: android:attr/fontVariationSettings and android:attr/ttcIndex not found,So make sure its available in your project.

Comment: i have search all the project i am not using android:attr/fontVariationSettings any where

Comment: I think ,its in xml file or any drawable file.